# When scrolling first page in NestedScrollView the second page will be scrolled underneath SliverPersistentHeader as well

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I have NestedScrollView as such:

```dart
headers: [
  SliverToBox(), // This scrolls away
  SliverPersistentHeader(), // This needs to pin
]
body: TabBarView() // Classic TabBar view with multiple pages
```

This is how it looks unscrolled:

[image]

This is how it looks when I start scrolling 1st page (all good so far):

[image]

And this is how it looks when I swipe to the next tab. Notice that the next page is already scrolled a little bit (starts from 2 and it should start from 0). The difference is in height of PersistentSliverHeader, basically second page gets scrolled underneath the header. How can I make the scroll on page 1 not affect the scroll on page 2?

[image]

Code: Here is the Gist, unfortunately it doesn't work on web/dartpad but on mobile runs without issues: https://gist.github.com/itsJoKr/eca5b57c2f290f517862dcd118a16d4d

Comment: Here is the link to the open discussion about that problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81619

Comment: That is definitely one issue that I also encountered, but I would say it's a bit different issue. In that case problem is that scroll position is reset / e.g. widget is rebuilt. In my case problem is more that second page is scrolled underneath the SliverPersistentHeader.
Note that I'm not using regular "Material looking" AppBar + TabView, but have something more custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to use `SliverOverlapAbsorber`.

```dart
              SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
                  pinned: true,
                  delegate: ChipTabBarSliverDelegate2(
                    tabController,
                    [
                      'tab 1',
                      'tab 2',
                      'tab 3',
                    ],
                    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

And key this is handle. It's exactly for this as it says in the docs:

```
  // This widget takes the overlapping behavior of the SliverAppBar,
  // and redirects it to the SliverOverlapInjector below. If it is
  // missing, then it is possible for the nested "inner" scroll view
  // below to end up under the SliverAppBar even when the inner
  // scroll view thinks it has not been scrolled.
  // This is not necessary if the "headerSliverBuilder" only builds
  // widgets that do not overlap the next sliver.
```